# Problemas com onclick

Tags: android

Tenho 2 botões onde ao clicar vou pedir informação ao servidor e recebo em uma lista.

O problema é a ordem porque quando clico pela primeira vez no botão ele não me dá os dados que pretendo na lista de imediato da me sim os dados que estavam guardados no array anteriormente.

Exemplo se clicar no Botão 1 o objectivo era receber :

- 1
- 2
- 3

Ao clicar no botão 2 o objectivo era receber :

- A
- B
- C

o que acontece é que imaginemos que tinha clicado no botão 1 anteriormente mas de momento tou a clicar no botão 2 estou a receber os numeros mas se voltar a clicar no botão 2 já me encontro a receber as letras é um exeplo pratico vou colocar o código a baixo d0s meus botões :

```
public class btnpesquisaclicker implements Button.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            link = "http://dagobah.grifin.pt/tiagocoelho/oi.php";
            varjson="linhaNome";
            new Download().execute();

            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            b.setTitle(linhas2);

            b.setItems((linhas.toArray(new String[linhas.size()])), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    int j = 0;

                        for (j = 0; j <= linhas.size(); j++) {
                            if (j == which) {

                                btncoordenadas.setText(linhas.get(j));
                                link = "http://dagobah.grifin.pt/tiagocoelho/tumglinhas.php";

                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
                b.show();

        }
    }
    public class btnparagensclicker implements Button.OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            link = "http://dagobah.grifin.pt/tiagocoelho/Conexaotumg.php";
            varjson="linhaId";
            new Download().execute();


            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            b.setTitle(linhas2);

            b.setItems((linhas.toArray(new String[linhas.size()])), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    int j = 0;

                    for (j = 0; j <= linhas.size(); j++) {
                        if (j == which) {

                            btncoordenadas.setText(linhas.get(j));


                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            b.show();
        }
    }
```

**Onde vou buscar os dados :**

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

       dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Autenticando", "Contactando o servidor, por favor, aguarde alguns instantes.", true, false);
    }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

linhas.clear();

            dialog.dismiss();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsa = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   linhas2= jsa.getString(varjson);
                    linhas.add(linhas2);
                    btncoordenadas.setText(linhas2);

                }






            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Função Download AsyncTask :**

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL( link);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if( conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ){
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                }else{
                    InputStream err = conn.getErrorStream();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String out = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                String url_all_empresas =  link;

                final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url_all_empresas);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }
```